# Filter a reverse manytomany django in one line?

Tags: python, django, django-queryset, django-orm

these are my models.

```
class League(models.Model):
    league_name=models.CharField(max_length=20)
    league_id=models.IntegerField()

class LeagueAdministrator(models.Model):
    administrator = models.ManyToManyField(User)
    league = models.ManyToManyField('League')
```

Given that there can be more than one administrators for league: I want a single query which returns a query set with all the user objects who are administator of a specific league. This is what I do now.

```
league=League.objects.get(league_id=1)
usersids=LeagueAdministrator.objects.filter(league=league).values_list('administrator')
Administrators=User.objects.filter(id__in=usersids)
```

Thank you.

Comment: I don't think your model structure is right: I doubt *very* much you need a LeagueAdminstrator class with ManyToManys on both sides. Rather, LeagueAdministrator is itself the linking table in a many-to-many relationship, with *ForeignKey*s both sides.

Comment: I don't get it: what if there are many leagues and users which could play in many leagues? If you say I don't need many-to-many, but only foreign keys: in which case then I would need many-to-many fields? (if an example connected to my models comes to your mind)

Comment: But my point is that that *is* a many-to-many. Any many-to-many relationship has a linking table with foreign keys to both sides: the Django ManyToManyField just creates that table for you, and creates a Pythonic way of accessing the join. In your case, you're allowing each combination of League and User to have multiple LeagueAdministrators, which doesn't make sense: any person can only be an admin for each team once, even though they can administrate muliple teams and each team can have multiple admins.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
administrators = League.objects.filter(leagueadministrator__league__id=1).distinct()
```

[Documentation here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships)